# VB6 Connection to Remote mySQL server hangs application

Tags: mysql, vb6, adodb

I am using VB application which connect to MySQL database hosted remotely on real Web server.

While I try to insert min 50 records one by one it hangs my VB application and sometimes OS suggest to kill tasks.

I am using Mysql ODBC connector with ADO DB at VB.

My application need 4000 record to receive or send to database.
What is best and fast way to connect VB and MySql in this case.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really  need to insert the record one by one, you should make a DoEvents after each insertion.

```
For i = 1 To 4000
    ' Insert record
    ' ......

    DoEvents
Next i
```

Doevents prevents Deadlocking and allows other Application events to be processed.

(Sometimes using Doevents loops may take a little longer)